# how to apply time windows with different lengths to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, each row represent a sale transaction:

```
startDate           INDEX_250   priceDeal
2013-05-02 00:00:00 9312.000    255000.000
2013-09-17 00:00:00 11121.000   368209.000
2013-10-09 00:00:00 11121.000   254000.000
2013-11-14 00:00:00 11121.000   520000.000
2013-11-22 00:00:00 11121.000   201000.000
2014-02-05 00:00:00 11121.000   260000.000
2014-02-28 00:00:00 11121.000   425000.000
2014-03-01 00:00:00 11121.000   315000.000
2014-03-11 00:00:00 9312.000    427000.000
2014-04-27 00:00:00 9312.000    138070.000
2014-06-20 00:00:00 9312.000    270000.000
2014-07-21 00:00:00 9312.000    282000.000
2014-07-31 00:00:00 9312.000    308806.350
2014-09-27 00:00:00 11121.000   170000.000
2014-10-05 00:00:00 11121.000   171658.220
2014-10-11 00:00:00 11121.000   292000.000
2014-10-13 00:00:00 11121.000   125000.000
2014-10-30 00:00:00 9312.000    95000.000
2014-11-18 00:00:00 9312.000    158942.280
2015-01-25 22:00:00 11121.000   238829.370
2015-03-11 00:00:00 11121.000   180695.960
2015-03-14 00:00:00 9312.000    320932.860
2015-03-21 00:00:00 11121.000   139872.000
2015-09-04 00:00:00 11121.000   140000.000
2015-09-09 00:00:00 9312.000    235000.000
```

i want to see how many sales transactions happened in previous 30 day `nrTargets_gr_250_30` and 60 day `nrTargets_gr_250_60` for each (grouped by) `INDEX_250` from the first sale transaction `2013-09-17`. example dataset is only for one `INDEX_250` but there are other index numbers as well, following out put is desirable:

```
      startDate  INDEX_250  nrTargets_gr_250_30 nrTargets_gr_250_60
      2013-10-17    11121   2.000               2.000
      2013-11-16    11121   1.000               3.000
      2013-12-16    11121   1.000               2.000
      2014-01-15    11121   0.000               1.000
      2014-02-14    11121   1.000               1.000
      2014-03-16    11121   2.000               3.000
      2014-04-15    11121   0.000               2.000
      2014-10-12    11121   3.000               3.000
      2014-11-11    11121   1.000               4.000
      2014-12-11    11121   0.000               1.000
      2015-02-09    11121   1.000               1.000
      2015-03-11    11121   0.000               1.000
      2015-04-10    11121   2.000               2.000
      2015-05-10    11121   0.000               2.000
      2015-09-07    11121   1.000               1.000
      2015-10-07    11121   0.000               1.000
      2016-02-04    11121   1.000               1.000
      2016-03-05    11121   0.000               1.000
      2017-01-29    11121   1.000               1.000
```

Comment: Can you provide data with two indexes?

Comment: @QuangHoang i made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you want *startDate* changed to the end of the respective
30-days period, starting from your start date.

Another detail is that you want the result **grouped** by *INDEX_250* -
how many previous transactions (in both respective periods) were with
**the same** value of *INDEX_250*.

Note also that *rolling* calculations can be performed on a window
containing rows from a number of **future** periods, whereas you want
the number of transactions from **previous** 30 or 60 days and
*rolling* does not allow negative number of periods.

This is why I took a different approach than "ordinary" *rolling*.

Start from auxiliary variables:

```
td30 = pd.Timedelta('30D')
dRng = pd.date_range(start='2013-09-17', end=df.startDate.max() + td30,
    freq='30D', closed='left')
```

Then define the following function computing both targets:

```
def targets(grp):
    grp['Prd'] = grp.startDate.apply(lambda x: dRng.asof(x) + td30)
    grp.set_index('Prd', inplace=True)
    trg30 = grp.groupby(level=0).INDEX_250.count()\
        .rename('nrTargets_gr_250_30').reindex(dRng, fill_value=0)
    trg60 = trg30.rolling(2).sum().rename('nrTargets_gr_250_60')\
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
    trg30 = trg30[trg30 > 0]
    trg60 = trg60[trg60 > 0]
    return trg30.to_frame().join(trg60, how='outer')\
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer').rename_axis('startDate')
```

Apply it and reset indices (just in this order, to have proper ordering of columns):

```
df2 = df[df.startDate >= '2013-09-17'].groupby('INDEX_250')\
    .apply(targets).reset_index(level=[0]).reset_index()
```

Notes:

- I took only rows with *startDate* on or after the start date you
  specified (*2013-09-17*).
- The type of both *target* columns is *int*. I think it is more natural,
  as these column contain the **number** of transactions, which by nature
  is just an **integer**.

And the last thing is to change the type of *INDEX_250* to *int*:

```
df2.INDEX_250 = df2.INDEX_250.astype(int)
```

The result for *INDEX_250* group is just as you specified, excluding
result rows from *2016* and *2017*, which were not included in your
sample data.

## Extended version - with average prices

To extend the result by average prices for each "final" date
and both targets, two changes are required.

First, define another function to "reformat" *target* DataFrame:

```
def trgReformat(trg):
    trg = trg[trg.nrTargets_gr_250 > 0].copy()
    trg['avgPrice'] = trg.sm / trg.nrTargets_gr_250
    return trg.drop(columns='sm')
```

Second, define *targets* function as:

```
def targets(grp):
    grp['Prd'] = grp.startDate.apply(lambda x: dRng.asof(x) + td30)
    grp.set_index('Prd', inplace=True)
    trg30 = grp.groupby(level=0).agg(
        nrTargets_gr_250=('INDEX_250', 'count'), sm=('priceDeal', 'sum'))\
        .reindex(dRng, fill_value=0)
    trg60 = trg30.rolling(2).sum().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
    trg30 = trgReformat(trg30)
    trg60 = trgReformat(trg60)
    return trg30.join(trg60, how='outer', lsuffix='_30', rsuffix='_60')\
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer').rename_axis('startDate')
```

This function uses *named aggregations*, to compute:

- *nrTargets_gr_250* - the number of rows,
- *sm* - sum of prices.

The reason is that computing of *trg60* is performed using *rolling* (for
2 consecutive 30-day periods), so *average* alone would be not sufficient
here.

Computation of the average price can be performed as late as in reformatting
of each *target*.

Application of this function is just as before.

Comment: thanks alot, it works, how can i change it in a way that for each time window instead of calculating number of transactions i also calculate average `priceDeal` of transactions in past 30day and 60 days?